# How to fix VGG16 ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,4) into shape (20)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Some problem with CNN Keras VGG16.

What is doing here is trying to use CNN to train some images with Keras and VGG16. It seems that it cannot take image size 32. Even I change it to 48, I still get an error.

```
---> 32         labels[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
     33         i += 1
     34         if i * batch_size >= sample_count:

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,4) into shape (20)
```

My code is below. It is using Keras VGG16 to train cats, dogs, frogs, crabs. It gets input array shape error:

```
from keras.applications import VGG16
conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                  include_top=False, 
                  input_shape=(32, 32, 3)) 

conv_base.summary()


import os
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
base_dir = '../cat_dog_frog_crab/cat_dog_frog_crab' 
train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'trainS') 
val_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'valS') 
test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'testS')

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) 
batch_size = 20

from keras.applications import VGG16
conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                  include_top=False, 
                  input_shape=(32, 32, 3)) 

def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 4, 4, 512)) 
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count))
    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory, 
        target_size=(32, 32), 
        batch_size=batch_size, 
        class_mode='categorical')
    i=0
    print ("before for loop")
    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch 
        labels[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        if i * batch_size >= sample_count:
            break
    return features, labels

train_features, train_labels = extract_features(train_dir, 2000) 
validation_features, validation_labels = extract_features(val_dir, 1000) 
test_features, test_labels = extract_features(test_dir, 1000)

train_features = np.reshape(train_features, (2000, 4 * 4 * 512))
validation_features = np.reshape(validation_features, (1000, 4 * 4 * 512))
test_features = np.reshape(test_features, (1000, 4 * 4 * 512))

from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras import optimizers
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', input_dim=4 * 4 * 512))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['acc'])


history = model.fit(train_features, train_labels, 
                    epochs=30,
                    batch_size=20,
                    validation_data=
                    (validation_features,validation_labels))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use below code and let me know if you're facing any issue.**

```
from keras.applications import VGG16
conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                  include_top=False, 
                  input_shape=(32, 32, 3)) 

conv_base.summary()


import os
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
base_dir = '../cat_dog_frog_crab/cat_dog_frog_crab' 
train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'trainS') 
val_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'valS') 
test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'testS')

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) 
batch_size = 20

from keras.applications import VGG16
conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                  include_top=False, 
                  input_shape=(32, 32, 3)) 

def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 4, 4, 512)) 
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, num_of_categories)) # Changes have been done here.@borarak's explanation is right.
    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory, 
        target_size=(32, 32), 
        batch_size=batch_size, 
        class_mode='categorical')
    i=0
    print ("before for loop")
    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch 
        labels[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        if i * batch_size >= sample_count:
            break
    return features, labels

train_features, train_labels = extract_features(train_dir, 2000) 
validation_features, validation_labels = extract_features(val_dir, 1000) 
test_features, test_labels = extract_features(test_dir, 1000)

train_features = np.reshape(train_features, (2000, 4 * 4 * 512))
validation_features = np.reshape(validation_features, (1000, 4 * 4 * 512))
test_features = np.reshape(test_features, (1000, 4 * 4 * 512))

from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras import optimizers
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', input_dim=4 * 4 * 512))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['acc'])


history = model.fit(train_features, train_labels, 
                    epochs=30,
                    batch_size=20,
                    validation_data=
                    (validation_features,validation_labels))
```

Comment: Found 1675 images belonging to 4 classes.
before for loop

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                
---> 31         features[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch
     32         labels[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
     33         i += 1

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (15,1,1,512) into shape (20,4,4,512)

Comment: @Nerdy If you have found my answer useful please accept my answer and upvote. Regarding your second issue, it is just because of shape mismatch. Will update you on your second issue soon.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is quite clear from the error message you see. You are trying to assign your `label` which is of shape `(20)` with values of size `(20,4)`. This happens because you choose `class_mode='categorical'` in your `flow_from_directory(...)` and thus your labels are one hot-encoded. Your `labels` should instead be something like `labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, num_of_categories))`